# Rails, Redis, Linux bin file error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, redis, bin

i am attempting to get redis-server running in my rails app. i am following this post [here](http://www.jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html) (the version numbers are a little outdated) but it seems from the error i am getting

```
@rob:~/Work/boogle[master]$ redis-server
bash: /usr/local/bin/redis-server: No such file or directory
```

that the file isnt being found! as you can see its looking for it in `/usr/local/bin/` the post i am following suggested that i `cp src/redis-server src/redis-cli /usr/bin` which suggests that `/usr/local/bin/` and `/usr/bin` are different bin files is it safe to just `cp src/redis-server src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin` i am a little scared to mess with the bin files, and creating a '`redis`-ception ' by running redis-server in the home dir.

I have a bad feeling like my bin or .bashrc file is F'd, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide asks you to install redis via the source.

You don't need this.

You can simply install redit with apt :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rwky/redis
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

Comment: `@rob:~/Work/boogle[master]$ redis-server`
`bash: /usr/local/bin/redis-server: No such file or directory`
still the same thing